# how to get the php home page using wampserver2.4

Tags: localhost

I had installed wampserver 2.4..if i'm connecting using online and it automatically get opens the localhost(home) page.. but the iis7(internet information services) page were displaying..how can get the home page instead of iis7 page

Comment: Do you want to have both running or just WAMP?

Comment: You can't run two webservers on the same port at the same time. You'll need to either shutdown IIS, or run wampserver on a different port or interface. I'd suggest running a proper lamp stack on a VM instead, and reading up on the whole process - It'll be more useful to actually understand the fundamentals rather than focusing entirely on the current issue

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of IIS, you would've to disable the www service.

type **services.msc** from the **run** command prompt > scroll down to **World Wide Publishing** service.

or go to **Control Panel** > **Administrative Tools** > **Services.msc** > **World Wide Publishing** service.